# Solving Linear Equations & similar Algebra Problems with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and I am trying to write a simple script that solves linear equations. So far my script solves linear equations that are plus and minus only such as "2x + 28 - 18x = 36 - 4x + 10". I want it to also be able to solve linear equations/algebra problems that contain multiplication and division such as "2x * 3x = 4 / 2x".

I kind of have an idea of what to do next but I think the script I have right now maybe overly complex and it's only going to make it more complicated to add the multiplication and division.

Below is my script. I'm hoping for a few pointers on how I could improve and simplify what I already have and what the best way to add multiplication and division?

My script on JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/ufekug/1/edit

My script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Problem Solver</title>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    // Total Xs on each side of equation
    // Example problem: 5x + 2 = 10 - 2x
    var leftSideXTotal = 0; // 5
    var rightSideXTotal = 0; // -2

    // Total integers on each side of equation
    // Example problem: 5x + 2 = 10 - 2x
    var leftSideIntTotal = 0; // 2
    var rightSideIntTotal = 0; // 10


    // Enter a math problem to solve
    var problem = "5x + 2 = 10 - 2x";


    // Remove all spaces in problem
    // Example problem: 5x + 2 = 10 - 2x
    problem = problem.replace(/\s/g,''); // 5x+2=10-2x

    // Add + signs in front of all - signs
    // Example problem: 5x + 2 = 10 - 2x
    problem = problem.replace(/-/gi, "+-"); // 5x+2=10+-2x

    // Split problem into left and right sides
    // Example problem: 5x + 2 = 10 - 2x
    var problemArray = problem.split("=");
    var problemLeftSide = problemArray[0]; // 5x+2
    var problemRightSide = problemArray[1]; // 10+-2x

    // Split values on each side into an array
    var problemLeftSideValues = problemLeftSide.split("+");
    var problemRightSideValues = problemRightSide.split("+");

    // Go through the left side values and add them up
    for (var i = 0; i < problemLeftSideValues.length; i++) {

        // Current value
        var currentValue = problemLeftSideValues[i];
        // Length of current value
        var currentValueLength = currentValue.length;

        if (currentValue.charAt(currentValueLength - 1) == "x") { //Check if current value is a X value

            // Remove X from end of current value
            currentValue = currentValue.split("x");

            // Add to total Xs on left side
            leftSideXTotal = Number(leftSideXTotal) + Number(currentValue[0]);

        } else {

            // Add to total integers on left side
            leftSideIntTotal = Number(leftSideIntTotal) + Number(problemLeftSideValues[i]);

        }
    }

    // Go through the right side values and add them up
    for (var i = 0; i < problemRightSideValues.length; i++) {

        // Current value
        var currentValue = problemRightSideValues[i];
        // Length of current value
        var currentValueLength = currentValue.length;

        if (currentValue.charAt(currentValueLength - 1) == "x") { //Check if current value is a X value

            // Remove X from end of current value
            currentValue = currentValue.split("x");

            // Add to total Xs on right side
            rightSideXTotal = Number(rightSideXTotal) + Number(currentValue[0]);

        } else {

            // Add to total integers on right side
            rightSideIntTotal = Number(rightSideIntTotal) + Number(problemRightSideValues[i]);

        }
    }

    // Compute
    var totalXs = (leftSideXTotal - rightSideXTotal)
    var totalIntegers = (rightSideIntTotal - leftSideIntTotal)
    var solution = (totalIntegers / totalXs)

    // Display solution
    document.getElementById("divSolution").innerText = solution;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="divSolution"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a pretty interesting question. I think you could attract more answerers if you shortened the title.

Comment: `2x * 3x = 4 / 2x` isn't really a linear equation.

Comment: Edited title. Changed linear equations to linear equations and similar algebra problems.

Comment: There is a problem in your question: `2x * 3x = 4 / 2x` is not solvable using normal simplification, it is quadratic on the left side.

Comment: have a look at [Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation).

Comment: Can you explain how you are going to implement with multiplication and division?

Comment: @Yoshi Yeah, Polish can be used, still we will have to first convert the left and right side, then split out x components and scalars and then use stack to compute each side separately. Am I right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to write (or use) an operator-precedence parser.

The idea is to turn the equation into a tree, e.g.

```
x + 3 = 3x - 2
```

Is really the structure

```
        =
     /     \
    +       -
   / \     / \
  x   3   *   2
         / \
        3   x
```

Where each operator describes an operation between two "branches" of the tree. Using a javascript object it shouldn't be difficult to create the structure:

```
function tree(lterm,op,rterm) {
   t.operator = op;
   t.left = lterm;
   t.right = rterm;
   return t;
}

expression = tree("x", "/", tree("x","+",3) );  //    x / (x+3)
```

Then by manipulating the tree you can resolve the equation, or carry out calculations. To evaluate an expression (with no unknowns), you run through the tree starting at the terminals, and upwards from intersection to intersection. You can replace a section of the tree with a result, or annotate it with a result - add a result variable to the `tree` object.

Here are some useful methods to include in a tree class:

- getLeft
- getRight
- prettyPrint
- evaluate
- evaluate("x",5) // x=5, now evaluate
  ...

It's not just linear operations that can be "parsed" this way. Better parsers will have a list of operators that includes =*/+- but also unary operators: - ( ) sin cos...

I haven't used an operator-precedence parser in javascript, but some must exist prewritten. Surely a kind soul on this site will add a good link or two to my answer.

BTW, the tree approach has many applications. In a spreadsheet:

```
A2 = A1+B1
```

In a boolean solver:

```
A = not (B or C)
C = true
```

In XML parsing:

```
<main>
  <part>A</part>
  <part>B</part>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have defined two functions:

`getTotalX()` : It will give you the count of `x` for any input string.

`getTotalScalars()` : It will give you the total of scalars (numbers).

And finally, your updated code (it still does only addition and subtraction):

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    // Total Xs on each side of equation
    // Example problem: 5x + 2 = 10 - 2x
    var leftSideXTotal = 0; // 5
    var rightSideXTotal = 0; // -2

    // Total integers on each side of equation
    // Example problem: 5x + 2 = 10 - 2x
    var leftSideIntTotal = 0; // 2
    var rightSideIntTotal = 0; // 10


    // Enter a math problem to solve
    var problem = "5x + 2 = 10 - 2x";


    // Remove all spaces in problem
    // Example problem: 5x + 2 = 10 - 2x
    problem = problem.replace(/\s/g,''); // 5x+2=10-2x

    // Add + signs in front of all - signs
    // Example problem: 5x + 2 = 10 - 2x
    problem = problem.replace(/-/gi, "+-"); // 5x+2=10+-2x

    // Split problem into left and right sides
    // Example problem: 5x + 2 = 10 - 2x
    var problemArray = problem.split("=");
    var problemLeftSide = problemArray[0]; // 5x+2
    var problemRightSide = problemArray[1]; // 10+-2x

    leftSideXTotal = getTotalX(problemLeftSide);
    leftSideIntTotal = getTotalScalars(problemLeftSide);

    rightSideXTotal = getTotalX(problemRightSide);
    rightSideIntTotal = getTotalScalars(problemRightSide);

    // Compute
    var totalXs = (leftSideXTotal - rightSideXTotal)
    var totalIntegers = (rightSideIntTotal - leftSideIntTotal)
    var solution = (totalIntegers / totalXs)

    // Display solution
    document.getElementById("divSolution").innerText = solution;

    // Find the total number of X in the string
    function getTotalX(data) {
        data = data.replace(/\s/g,'');
        xCount = 0;

        if(data.indexOf('x') != -1) {
            if (data.indexOf('+') != -1) {
                data = data.split('+');

                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    xCount += getTotalX(data[i]);
                }
            } else if (data.indexOf('-') != -1) {
                data = data.split('-');

                // Single negative
                if(data[0] == "") {
                    xCount -= getTotalX(data[1]);
                } else {
                    xCount += getTotalX(data[0]);

                    for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
                        xCount -= getTotalX(data[i]);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                xCount = parseInt(data.split('x')[0]);
            }
        }

        return xCount;
    }

    // Find the total of scalars
    function getTotalScalars(data) {
        data = data.replace(/\s/g,'');
        intCount = 0;

        if (data.indexOf('+') != -1) {
            data = data.split('+');

            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                intCount += getTotalScalars(data[i]);
            }
        } else if (data.indexOf('-') != -1) {
            data = data.split('-');

            // Single negative
            if(data[0] == "") {
                intCount -= getTotalScalars(data[1]);
            } else {
                intCount += getTotalScalars(data[0]);

                for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
                    intCount -= getTotalScalars(data[i]);
                }
            }
        } else {
            if(data.indexOf('x') == -1) {
                intCount = parseInt(data.split('x')[0]);
            } else {
                intCount = 0;
            }
        }

        return intCount;
    }
}
</script>
```