# Processing of string

Tags: javascript

I have following input for instance as a string:

```
(-4-1+255*4)^4
```

I also have some functions:

1. modulo(a, mod) => counts basic modulo
2. divideModulo (a, b, n) => divide operation for modulo
3. exponenatation(base, exp, mod) => exp operation for modulo etc.

I need to transform this string to:

```
exponenation(modulo(modulo(-4, mod) - modulo(-1, mod) + modulo(255, mod) * modulo(4, mod), mod), 2, mod)
```

Also string can contain / and square root and priority of signs must be preserved.

Right now, I am trying to do something like this:

```
 var counter = 0;
    var res = getNumbers(string); // return only numbers from string
    var x = retezec.match(/\d+|\D/g); ( // returns array with numbers and string divided. Problem is // that "- digit" at the beginning is not added right now
    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        if(!isNaN(x[i])){
            x[i] = " modulo(" + res[counter] + ", " +  mod + ") ";
            counter++;
        }
    }
```

But it does not work as I need.
Thanks for help

Comment: Taking apart a string into a structure is called parsing. Here, your string has numbers and operator signs, so you need an "operator precedence parser". In this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191678/solving-linear-equations-similar-algebra-problems-with-javascript/14199809#14199809 I explain the idea a bit.

Comment: Plus, don't write a parser all by yourself (unless you're at uni and your teachers are asking you to...) look for one from elsewhere.

Comment: tthanks, would you recommend me any parser which can do what i desribed please? :)

Comment: Haven't used one in js... https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+formula+parser gives options, the first looks overkill, but fparse might be OK, or the mathjs.org one.

Comment: thanks. But it will solve the problem that I can run some functions from string not the actual transformation to the string which contains that functions, am I right?